# Bulk Adding Users to Groups

Tags: scripting

Let's assume I have a Linux box configured as a primary domain controller with 50 users connecting at any given time. If I wanted to create two groups, one called "Teachers" and the other "Students" How could I script something so I wouldn't have to individually type out each command for each user when adding them to their appropriate group?

This is what scripting is all about yes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A loop in this format will work:

```
while read i ; do 
    command_name "$i"
done < filename
```

The file named `filename` would contain a list of users, one per line. For the command name `command_name` use `useradd -G {group-name}`.

Answer (score 2):

Change group1 and group2 to your desired groups, and use `-M user1,user2,user3,...` as the users.

```
for group in group1 group2
do gpasswd -M user1,user2,... $group
done
```